# What does "catch it on the chin" mean?

Tags: idioms

As in topic, what does "catch it on the chin" idiom mean? I tried to google it, but every hit is on webpages that use this idiom, never explain it.

Comment: Can you give the context in which you saw it used? (And what do you mean by "As in topic?")

Comment: If you meant an idiom, it is actually, "take it on the chin", not "catch it ...".

Comment: Voting to close as "Too Localised". Google Books - ["catch it on the chin"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22catch+it+on+the+chin%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 5 results, against ["**take** it on the chin"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22take+it+on+the+chin%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 89,300 results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is true that expressions like [having a chin](http://www.ringsidebygus.com/boxing-terms.html) are used in boxing to express "having the ability to absorb punches when you get hit with a big shot and stay standing", my understanding of "catch it on the chin" is that it means to be struck a severe blow and not receive it well.  At [boxing.isport.com](http://boxing.isport.com/boxing-guides/basic-boxing-defense) boxers are advised "Tuck your chin to your front shoulder to limit the effect of punches landed on your head", and at [heavyfists.com](http://heavyfists.com/how-to-take-a-punch), "If you think you have a weak chin or a glass jaw, bulk up your neck."  Even so, letting a punch get to your head is a failure of defense, and to take a hit on the chin is to risk being knocked out.  The idea is to catch punches on your gloves, on your elbows, *not* on your chin, because rapid head motion bumps the brain into the skull, which is the usual knockout mechanism.

As mentioned in a comment, *[thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Chin)* lists *take it on the chin*:

> take it on the chin and take it on the nose
>   1. Lit. to stand up to something adverse, such as criticism. (Fig. on taking a direct punch to the head in boxing.) They laid some blunt criticism on him, but he took it on the chin. I knew he could take it on the nose.
>   2. Fig. to receive the full brunt of something. Why do I have to take it on the chin for something I didn't do? If you did it, you have to learn to take it on the chin.

However, *take it on the chin* is not the same as *catch it on the chin*, which as I explained above indicates a failure of defense.

Comment: btw, the OP talks of an idiom. "catch it ..." is not an idiom, only a common phrase in boxing. Let's clarify this to the OP thru' a comment.

Comment: @Kris, or by a tag edit; eg -idioms, +meaning

Comment: Both phrases imply the same thing, when used as a metaphor: it is risky to do so but when you do, you show courage and endurance. More details are at the answer by @Brett Reynolds. Together the three answers seem to make for a comprehensive explanation -- a wiki, don't they?

Answer (score 2):

***undaunted***; not cowed down by; cf. "face it".

also, ***take*** it on the chin  (see on idioms.thefreedictionary.com)

Comment: Source, please?

Comment: By now, I've edited that in as well. Can't paste url, though, sorry.

Comment: The figurative definitions I see for "take it on the chin" are more about taking the full brunt of something or enduring trouble. See: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Chin

Answer (score 1):

If a fighter takes a hit on the chin, it will whip his head around because of the leverage. It other words, it will be a very effective hit. Thus, in general, taking something on the chin is not a good thing. It means you take the full hit of it. On the other hand, if you willingly take something on the chin, it's a brave thing to do. As Kris says, you face it without turning away.